# JAXB - Representing the root element as a list of custom types

Tags: jaxb

Similar to this question asked on Stackoverflow, [using JAXB to represent a list as the root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729385/using-jaxb-to-represent-a-list-as-the-root-element), I have the same issue. Though the solution outlined in the answer doesn't work for me.

*Note:* I am using the Jackson fasterxml lib for doing the mappings.

Essentialy I am consuming some XML from an API (the recurly api). One of the messages returned  by the API has the root element as a list, a demonstration is shown below:

```
<plans type="array">
    <plan href="...">
    ...
    </plan>
    <plan href="...">
    ...
    </plan>
</plans>
```

I created the following Java class + JAXB annotations to capture the above:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "plans")
public class Plans extends RecurlyObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "plan", type = Plan.class)
    private List<Plan> plans;

    public List<Plan> getPlans() { return this.plans; }

    public void setPlans(final List<Plan> plans) { this.plans = plans; }
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work. The docs & articles I have read all demo the above using Strings rather than custom types for the elements of the list.

Running the above generates the following error:

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value
   of type [simple type, class com.ning.billing.recurly.model.Plan] from JSON String; no 
   single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: 
   com.ning.billing.recurly.model.Plans["plan"])

I also tried the following - but generates a similar issue:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "plans")
public class Plans extends RecurlyObject {
    @XmlTransient
    public static final String PLANS_RESOURCE = "/plans";

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "plans")
    @XmlElement(name = "plan", type = Plan.class)
    private List<Plan> plans;

    public List<Plan> getPlans() { return this.plans; }

    public void setPlans(final List<Plan> plans) { this.plans = plans; }
    ...
}
```

The only way I can it to not error is if I create a ctor on my Plan class that takes a String. But then my `List<Plan>` is a list of Plan objects, one for every sub node of all of the Plans :(

BTW - the Plan Java class works fine - I use it to receive individual Plan messages from other API calls.

So, any ideas how to correctly map a root element which is a list of things other than Strings into a Java object using JAXB?

Cheers

**UPDATE**

The following solution was provided by [Pierre](https://github.com/pierre) outside of stackoverflow.

It is possible to get this to work with Jackson see the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "plans")
public class Plans extends RecurlyObjects<Plan> {
}
```

The important details to note is `extends RecurlyObjects<Plan>`. `RecurlyObjects` is essentially an `ArrayList`.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class RecurlyObjects<T extends RecurlyObject> extends ArrayList<T> {
}
```

This now works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default you should annotate the property.  I've simplified your mapping where possible.

```
package forum11748159;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Plans extends RecurlyObject {

    private List<Plan> plans;

    @XmlElement(name = "plan")
    public List<Plan> getPlans() { return this.plans; }

    public void setPlans(final List<Plan> plans) { this.plans = plans; }

}
```

If you want to annotate the fields you need to add the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation to your class:

```
package forum11748159;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "plans")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Plans extends RecurlyObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "plan")
    private List<Plan> plans;

    public List<Plan> getPlans() { return this.plans; }

    public void setPlans(final List<Plan> plans) { this.plans = plans; }

}
```

---

> Note: I am using the Jackson fasterxml lib for doing the mappings.

Jackson offers some support for JAXB annotations, but as far as I know is not a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) compliant implementation.  It is not guaranteed to interpret JAXB annotations according to the specification.

Comment: Hi Blaise - I had just come to the conclusion myself that it is to do with using Jackson. I can get it to work if I use the Jersey client to do the mapping. I tried out your suggestions but got the same result. I am accepting this as the answer as you have high-lighted the likely real issue which is how we are using Jackson. Cheers