# Dynamic JSON structure to Java structure

Tags: java, json

I'm working on a project to use JSON as a configuration framework for creating Java objects.  This is also my first professional Java project  coming from years of experience in CF/PHP/JS etc...

EVERY resource I can find on converting JSON to Java is predicated on the idea that you have to manually build the object in Java first, a POJO, and then use the JSON to populate it.

As a web language veteran, I'm choking on this idea.  I get that compiled languages play differently, but I thought it was a tenet developers from command line to machine language shared: "If you have to do it more than twice, automate it."

...and yet it seems like the presiding Java wisdom is: Do the tedious structure building by hand, every time, then use GSON/Jackson/whatever to populate the rigid structure.  If your JSON changes (and it will, because JSON) do the whole thing over again.

Is there a parallel to the web code way of thinking?
1) Load JSON
2) Build native language structure based on JSON structure.
3) Populate new object with data from structure.
4) Use object however you wish.

(As @Thomas pointed out, the most accurate scenario for why this would be necessary is a API response that returns JSON, it might be different periodically, and while duck typing is generally uncomfortable for high level languages, even converting EVERYTHING to a string saves effort and time compared to rebuilding your framework every time {or having a tool that converts your JSON from myriad sources to be usable by any other tool}.  Again, it seems obvious from the perspective of cowboy languages, but so foreign to the high level languages people aren't understanding the question.)

Comment: If you don't want POJOs just use a `Map`. Otherwise, as Java is compiled, you need to define the structure of the incoming data. You can use a JSON schema, and [compile that to POJOs](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo).

Comment: Java developers are just happy to have GSON and Jackson for automatic JSON parsing. Java doesn't play well with "duck typing" it's just how it goes. Other high level languages are the same, i.e. C#, Swift, Objective-C, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marshall/Unmarshall a JSON to a Java class using JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938428/marshall-unmarshall-a-json-to-a-java-class-using-jaxb)

Comment: There are libraries which are able to create POJOs from JSON but you'd still have to somehow access the properties of those objects and without knowing them at compile time the only way to do this would be reflection - which then wouldn't provide much advantage (if any) over using maps. If your only problem is that properties might be added or removed then you could just configure the mapper to ignore those.

Comment: One lib to create pojos from json would be this: https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo - this works with a json schema or plain json (you'd have to make sure the plain json contains all properties though)

Comment: `... and yet it seems like the presiding Java wisdom is: Do the tedious structure building by hand, every time ...` - I'd say that in the Java world you probably mostly encounter 2 situations: 1) you define an api in which case the pojo comes _first_ (and the json schema/definition is created from it) or 2) you're working against some json api which already provides a pojo definition (or at least a json schema to generate pojos from). Most tutorials/sites you found are probably focusing on 1) since that's probably more common in the Java world as well as easier to explain.

Comment: "_Use object however you wish_". You're missing the point here. _How_ would you use these objects? You can not know of their existence before reading the JSON, therefore you cannot write _any_ code against them. You cannot write any code that accesses their properties of processes them in any way as they do not exist. If you do want to interact with them then you have to use reflection, which is really no better than using a `Map` and accessing properties by `String` keys. I think you haven't thought far enough ahead in terms of how this would _physically_ work.

Comment: That WAS the point I was trying to get to and I figured it out.  If I was working in PHP for instance, and wrote a function that parsed JSON, the nature of that JSON object would irrelevant from the PARSER'S perspective: This JSON object has an array in it, so add an array to the PHP object and populate it with the values... at run-time on the fly.  The code that calls the parser later can pass it any valid JSON and get back a valid PHP object, and the CALLER is responsible for knowing what it is looking for.  That workflow isn't viable in high level languages, so I'll do it long form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read carefully the comments above and I think there is a very common scenario where an **ad hoc** Java object would be extremely useful even if the API structure is known at compile time.

Lets say you deal with an API that return a complex JSON object in which you are only interested in a very specific property value.

Take as an example the folowing google map API call to get geo details givin an address:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sunnyvale,CA

As you can check and see, the response structure is quite complex. Assuming you only want to get the `lat` and `lng` properties value, there should be an easier way rather than predefine the complete corresponding Java class.

So yes, if you don't want to go with the strongly typed predefined Java class, you will need to use raw Object type and Maps. More specifically, a StringMap.

And now finally I can give a solution:

Ideally, you would like to access the properties with the same native notation like you would do in JS. Something like this:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address;
String responseStr = fetch(url);
JsonHelper response =  JsonHelper.forString(responseStr);

String status = (String) response.getValue("status");
if(status != null && status.equals("OK")) {
   lat = (Double) response.getValue("results[0].geometry.location.lat");        
   lng = (Double) response.getValue("results[0].geometry.location.lng");
}
```

The following  `JsonHelper` class code is taken from the [jello-framework](http://jello-framework.com) and it lets you do exactly that.

```
package jello.common;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.AbstractMap;

public class JsonHelper {

    private Object json;

    public JsonHelper(String jsonString) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        json = g.fromJson(jsonString, Object.class);
    }

    public static JsonHelper forString(String jsonString) {
        return new JsonHelper(jsonString);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object getValue(String path) {
        Object value = json;
        String [] elements = path.split("\\.");
        for(String element : elements) {
            String ename = element.split("\\[")[0];

            if(AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                value = ( (AbstractMap<String, Object>) value).get(ename);

                if(element.contains("[")) {
                    if(List.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                        Integer index = Integer.valueOf(element.substring(element.indexOf("[")+1, element.indexOf("]")) );
                        value = ((List<Object>) value).get(index);
                    }
                    else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn... that com.google.gson.internal package is a slippery fellow to find, and whats more I doubt my employer will be keen on my using it... but STILL... this is the solution I was looking for, even if I can't use it without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Guess what, this is your lucky day. Your comment push me to revise my solution and I found that com.google.gson.internal.StringMap extends java.util.AbstractMap 

so I simply replaced the ugly internal class with the public interface to get a working elegant JSON helper. Please check my revised answer.

Comment: HAH! Nice. Thanks.

Comment: +1 to the question and the answer. Ahh....just loved the question (same situation as mine) and an elegant solution. Many Thanks !!