# gson model for array

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a JSON file like following:

```
{
"count": 60,
"value": [{
            "changesetId": 60,
            "url": "http://...",
            "author": {
                "id": "...",
                "displayName": "*...",
                "uniqueName": "...",
                "url": "http://...*
                "imageUrl": "http://..."
            },
            "checkedInBy": {
                "id": "...",
                "displayName": "...",
                "uniqueName": "...",
                "url": "http://...",
                "imageUrl": "http://..."
            },
            "createdDate": "2016-11-08T22:05:11.17Z",
            "comment": "..."
        },
```

I am stuck at the point to create a model to use the API Gson. I started like:

```
public class Changesets{
    int count;
    *TODO* // model for the JSON above.
}
```

A start for the model or the entire model would be much appreciated. I will use this to deserialize.

Edit: I tried;

```
public class Changesets {
    int count;
    int changeset;
    String url;
    Changeset.Author author;
    Changeset.CheckedInBy checkedInBy;
    String createdDate;
    String comment;
}
```

Where I could successfully write Changeset model.

Comment: Try to read https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Collections-Examples

Comment: With all the respect why was I downvoted?

Comment: @terma not really what I want

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Does the edit help for showing that I really put an effort before I asked? Also, do you have an answer?

Comment: Guys, sometime I have a feeling we are too harsh with novice developers. Yes, we should strive for well formed questions but we also have the responsibility to welcome novices, try to determine from their question what is it that they are struggling to understand and ...answer their questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I am with you on that. In this specific case, the minimum code originally posted was the key to determine what he was struggling to understand and not an evidence of lack of effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to model the respective Java classes, you will need to reverse engineering the JSON structure.
In your case it will be something like this:

```
public class Changesets{
    int count;
    List<Change> value;
}
```

and I will let you complete the work.

However, if you only need an ad hoc Java object to deal with a complex JSON object in which you are only interested in a very specific property value, you can use the solution I suggested in this answer:
[Dynamic JSON structure to Java structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407198/dynamic-json-structure-to-java-structure/40433552#40433552)

Comment: You are wrong. Generic List<> is the Java way to describe arrays

Comment: just noticed after I asked. Thanks a lot