# How to parse nested JSON from Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I am using the below to map a json response to a Map

```
 Map<String, Object> apiResponse = restTemplate.postForObject("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+defaultLocation+"&key="+API_KEY, httpEntity, Map.class, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

I can use the below to output the entire JSON to a string

```
    String jsonResponse = apiResponse.get("results").toString();
```

However, what I want to get is a nested value which is `results->geometry->location`

I have tried a number of solution with `JSONArrays, JSONObjects, Substring` but can't get them to work.

Response JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New Zealand",
               "short_name" : "NZ",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Auckland, New Zealand",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -36.660571,
                  "lng" : 175.287137
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -37.065475,
                  "lng" : 174.4438016
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -36.8484597,
               "lng" : 174.7633315
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -36.660571,
                  "lng" : 175.287137
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -37.065475,
                  "lng" : 174.4438016
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ--acWvtHDW0RF5miQ2HvAAU",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Auckland",
               "short_name" : "Auckland",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New Zealand",
               "short_name" : "NZ",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "1010",
               "short_name" : "1010",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Auckland, 1010, New Zealand",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -36.8364659,
                  "lng" : 174.7838398
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -36.8621041,
                  "lng" : 174.7503805
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -36.8484597,
               "lng" : 174.7633315
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -36.8364659,
                  "lng" : 174.7838398
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -36.8621041,
                  "lng" : 174.7503805
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJuZqpSPtHDW0R4LOiQ2HvAAU",
         "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please share your json output and the code what u have tried

Comment: @PavneetSingh I have added the response JSON. The code has come and gone, so I can add what I have tried. Im really interested in the best approach if you have one?

Comment: check this answer. It is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407198/dynamic-json-structure-to-java-structure/40433552#40433552

Comment: You should convert the object which you get from `apiResponse.get(results)` to an JSONObject. In that way , you will access to all the elements inside it..

Comment: @ViChU How do I get nested values from a JSONObject? I tried but no luck?

Comment: @Yonkee please check my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(jsonresult);
// get result array
JSONArray resultsarray= obj.getJSONArray("results"); 
for (int i=0;i<resultsarray.length(),i++){
        // get Objects using index
        JSONObject jsonobject= results.getJSONObject(i);
        // get geometry object
        JSONObject geometry= jsonobject.getJSONObject("geometry");
        // get location object from geometry
        JSONObject location= geometry.getJSONObject("location");

        // get location values from location object
        double lat = location.optDouble("lat",0.0);
        double long = location.optDouble("lng",0.0);
 }
```

About `optDouble`

```
public double optDouble(String key, double defaultValue) {
```

> Get an optional double associated with a key, or the defaultValue if
>   there is no such key or if its value is not a number. If the value is
>   a string, an attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

Comment: Which JSONObject are you using? Mine doesn't support getJSONArray

Comment: @Yonkee i am using `org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: Boom, its working. I think I was using the wrong JSON library during my investigation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yonkee i am glad that it worked for you :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would like to access the properties with the same native notation like you would do in JS. Something like this:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address;
String responseStr = fetch(url);
JsonHelper response =  JsonHelper.forString(responseStr);

String status = (String) response.getValue("status");
if(status != null && status.equals("OK")) {
   lat = (Double) response.getValue("results[0].geometry.location.lat");        
   lng = (Double) response.getValue("results[0].geometry.location.lng");
}
```

The following  `JsonHelper` class code (taken from [jello-framework](http://jello-framework.com)) lets you do exactly that.

```
package jello.common;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.AbstractMap;

public class JsonHelper {

    private Object json;

    public JsonHelper(String jsonString) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        json = g.fromJson(jsonString, Object.class);
    }

    public static JsonHelper forString(String jsonString) {
        return new JsonHelper(jsonString);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object getValue(String path) {
        Object value = json;
        String [] elements = path.split("\\.");
        for(String element : elements) {
            String ename = element.split("\\[")[0];

            if(AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                value = ( (AbstractMap<String, Object>) value).get(ename);

                if(element.contains("[")) {
                    if(List.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
                        Integer index = Integer.valueOf(element.substring(element.indexOf("[")+1, element.indexOf("]")) );
                        value = ((List<Object>) value).get(index);
                    }
                    else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this, but still unsure how to get nested values? JSONHelper jsonHelper = new JSONHelper(apiResponse.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Use jackson api for parsing,it will be easy

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
        if(node.get("results").isArray()){
            for(int i=0; i <= node.get("results").size()-1; i++){
                System.out.println(node.get("results").get(i));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Gson api and was able to get the location. Try this :

**Code::**

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = "your json";

    JsonObject map = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class); // to be replaced with your restTemplate call
    JsonArray arr = map.getAsJsonArray("results");

    for (Object j : arr) {
        System.out.println(((JsonObject) j).get("geometry").getAsJsonObject().get("location"));
    }
```

**Console Output::**

```
{"lat":-36.8484597,"lng":174.7633315}
{"lat":-36.8484597,"lng":174.7633315}
```

So ideally just get the response as a `JsonObject` instead of a `Map` and you will be able to read the `location`.